# What `LCP TermReq` after `IPCP ConfReq id=0x2 <addr 0.0.0.0> <ms-dns1 0.0.0.0>...` means?

Tags: modem, point-to-point-protocol

What `LCP TermReq` after `IPCP ConfReq id=0x2 <addr 0.0.0.0> <ms-dns...` means?

Short snippet:

```
Sep 16 01:39:13 raspberrypi pppd[581]: rcvd [IPCP ConfRej id=0x1 <compress VJ 0f 01>]
Sep 16 01:39:13 raspberrypi pppd[581]: sent [IPCP ConfReq id=0x2 <addr 0.0.0.0> <ms-dns1 0.0.0.0> <ms-dns2 0.0.0.0>]
Sep 16 01:39:13 raspberrypi pppd[581]: rcvd [LCP TermReq id=0x2]
Sep 16 01:39:13 raspberrypi pppd[581]: LCP terminated by peer
Sep 16 01:39:13 raspberrypi pppd[581]: sent [LCP TermAck id=0x2]
Sep 16 01:39:16 raspberrypi pppd[581]: Connection terminated.
```

Long snippet:

```
Sep 16 01:39:12 raspberrypi pppd[581]: Serial connection established.
Sep 16 01:39:12 raspberrypi pppd[581]: using channel 3
Sep 16 01:39:12 raspberrypi pppd[581]: Using interface ppp0
Sep 16 01:39:12 raspberrypi pppd[581]: Connect: ppp0 <--> /dev/ttyAMA0
Sep 16 01:39:13 raspberrypi pppd[581]: rcvd [LCP ConfReq id=0x1 <asyncmap 0xa0000> <auth pap> <pcomp> <accomp>]
Sep 16 01:39:13 raspberrypi pppd[581]: sent [LCP ConfReq id=0x1 <asyncmap 0x0> <magic 0xd179369a> <pcomp> <accomp>]
Sep 16 01:39:13 raspberrypi pppd[581]: sent [LCP ConfAck id=0x1 <asyncmap 0xa0000> <auth pap> <pcomp> <accomp>]
Sep 16 01:39:13 raspberrypi pppd[581]: rcvd [LCP ConfNak id=0x1 <asyncmap 0xa0000>]
Sep 16 01:39:13 raspberrypi pppd[581]: sent [LCP ConfReq id=0x2 <asyncmap 0xa0000> <magic 0xd179369a> <pcomp> <accomp>]
Sep 16 01:39:13 raspberrypi pppd[581]: rcvd [LCP ConfAck id=0x2 <asyncmap 0xa0000> <magic 0xd179369a> <pcomp> <accomp>]
Sep 16 01:39:13 raspberrypi pppd[581]: sent [LCP EchoReq id=0x0 magic=0xd179369a]
Sep 16 01:39:13 raspberrypi pppd[581]: sent [PAP AuthReq id=0x1 user="raspberrypi" password=<hidden>]
Sep 16 01:39:13 raspberrypi pppd[581]: rcvd [LCP EchoRep id=0x0 magic=0x0]
Sep 16 01:39:13 raspberrypi pppd[581]: rcvd [PAP AuthAck id=0x1 ""]
Sep 16 01:39:13 raspberrypi pppd[581]: PAP authentication succeeded
Sep 16 01:39:13 raspberrypi kernel: [ 1302.222998] PPP BSD Compression module registered
Sep 16 01:39:13 raspberrypi kernel: [ 1302.269967] PPP Deflate Compression module registered
Sep 16 01:39:13 raspberrypi pppd[581]: sent [CCP ConfReq id=0x1 <deflate 15> <deflate(old#) 15> <bsd v1 15>]
Sep 16 01:39:13 raspberrypi pppd[581]: sent [IPCP ConfReq id=0x1 <compress VJ 0f 01> <addr 0.0.0.0> <ms-dns1 0.0.0.0> <ms-dns2 0.0.0.0>]
Sep 16 01:39:13 raspberrypi pppd[581]: rcvd [IPCP ConfReq id=0x1 <addr 192.168.254.254>]
Sep 16 01:39:13 raspberrypi pppd[581]: sent [IPCP ConfAck id=0x1 <addr 192.168.254.254>]
Sep 16 01:39:13 raspberrypi pppd[581]: rcvd [LCP ProtRej id=0x0 80 fd 01 01 00 0f 1a 04 78 00 18 04 78 00 15 03 2f]
Sep 16 01:39:13 raspberrypi pppd[581]: Protocol-Reject for 'Compression Control Protocol' (0x80fd) received
Sep 16 01:39:13 raspberrypi pppd[581]: rcvd [IPCP ConfRej id=0x1 <compress VJ 0f 01>]
Sep 16 01:39:13 raspberrypi pppd[581]: sent [IPCP ConfReq id=0x2 <addr 0.0.0.0> <ms-dns1 0.0.0.0> <ms-dns2 0.0.0.0>]
Sep 16 01:39:13 raspberrypi pppd[581]: rcvd [LCP TermReq id=0x2]
Sep 16 01:39:13 raspberrypi pppd[581]: LCP terminated by peer
Sep 16 01:39:13 raspberrypi pppd[581]: sent [LCP TermAck id=0x2]
Sep 16 01:39:16 raspberrypi pppd[581]: Connection terminated.
Sep 16 01:39:16 raspberrypi pppd[581]: Modem hangup
```

Does it mean that server does not like any client OS settings or some error on modem part?

Comment: It's been a *really* long time since I did anything with PPP, but I believe this means your `raspberrypi` PPP client is asking the far end to assign an IP address, and the far end can't or won't, so it terminates the connection. The far end would typically have a pool of addresses configured for dynamic assignment, and possibly also static assignments for known clients (typically based on login name).

Comment: Check the logs on the remote PPP server.